# compare values in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary contains keys and values:

```
dic1 = {'first': 13, 'second': 7, 'third': 5}
```

I want to compare the values and select key with the largest number: The output should be:

```
'first'
```

here is my code:

```
import operator
dic1 = {'first': 13, 'second': 7, 'third': 5}
total = [k:max(dic1.values()) for k,v in dic1.items()]
```

but I got `SyntaxError..` any help?

Comment: Hint: What is that `]` doing there when you're defining `dic1`? Also, for your `total =` line, it looks like you're trying to do a dictionary comprehension using list comprehension syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
max(dic1.items(), key=lambda key_value_pair: key_value_pair[1])[0]
```

The call to `max` returns a tuple `(key, value)`, and then you get the first entry in this tuple with `max(...)[0]`.

Comment: You can just do `max(dic1, key=dic1.get)`